# Heil gas Furnace -- water in the pressure switch vacuum hose

Tags: hvac

Every few days I have to remove and drain the the rubber tube from the pressure switch to the furnace or it won't ignite.  Why is water condensing in that tube?  It's not a hard thing to fix-- but I ought not to have to drain that tube at all. Seems to happen more often in colder weather.  I'd hate to be out of town for a few days, have the furnace not light and end up with frozen pipes!

Answer (score 1):

My American Standard has a drain trap that has to be flushed every so often or it will fill up the tubing and I can hear that it is affecting the ID fan. You may have a similar problem